# Making edits when rep under 2000

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I have noticed that if I make an edit before a 2000+ user, my edit is rejected by the community even though I sent it to que prior to said 2000+ user completing their edit. Why is this? Aren't edits supposed to lock from editing waiting for approval for those under 2k to get approved or denied?

[image]

I know my edit was in prior to this user completing their edit since I was commenting on the post when they finished their edit.

---

An edit can go to the que prior to a 2k+ user, get one approval 10mins ago, so the user couldn't have been editing for that long to start before me.
[image]

Comment: Hey, can you please suggest an edit to the answer below with the content "Do not approve or reject, this is a test." and then ping me here or in the comments there?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I cannot edit others post in meta but my own. The edit button is always grayed out.

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting. Thanks.

Comment: @AsafKaragila new meta post for that as well :)?

Comment: No no, no need for that. Thanks though!

Comment: I added an explanation of your second example. Note that "10 minutes ago" is time relative to when you took that screenshot. The time interval between your suggestion and rejection is shorter. Also, it's not impossible for an edit to be finished many minutes after it was started, if it's a substantial revision of the post.

Comment: I'll also say that the second post had far more serious problems than formatting; the version you edited was incomprehensible, and changing `\bar` to `\overline` does nothing there. The words "pig" and "lipstick" come to mind.

Comment: "so the user couldn't have been editing for that long to start before me." Umm, when I edit somebody's post, that can easily take more than five minutes. If there's much to do, easily longer than ten.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After your suggested edit is submitted, a 2000 user cannot *begin* their own edit without reviewing yours: if they click *edit (1)*, instead of the regular editor the system brings up your edit for review. I just experimented with this myself:

[image: edit view]

Pressing *Skip* here returns the user to the question window without any changes. Any of the other four buttons will constitute a review of the suggested edit.

However, if a 2K user begins  their  edit prior to you finishing it (and finishes it before your suggestion is fully approved), your suggestion will be rejected. The conflict between a suggestion and a real edit is always resolved in favor of the latter. See [Can we get a better conflict resolution to edits vs suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166861/can-we-get-a-better-conflict-resolution-to-edits-vs-suggested-edits).

#### Timeline of your [first example](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/302253)

1. You made your suggestion at 18:08:15
2. A 2K user posted their edit at 18:08:41; this resulted in the rejection of your suggested edit.

Chances are they began editing before 18:08:15.

#### Timeline of your [second example](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/302361)

1. Question was asked at 21:28:05
2. Your edit was suggested at 21:31:16
3. It got one approval vote 21:32:52 (one of two required votes for approval)
4. The author edited their post at 21:34:51; this resulted in the rejection of your suggested edit.

It seems that the author noticed a problem with their question immediately after posting, and began editing it. Their edit [was more than just formatting](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1023403/revisions), so I understand it took a while to type.  The author of a post has the privilege to edit it directly, so the edit conflict was resolved in their favor.